# Limit and Integral with exp

Tags: integration, limits

Suppose $f \in \mathbb{R} \text{ on } [0,A]\ \forall A < \infty$ and $f(x) \rightarrow 1 \text{ as } x \rightarrow \infty$.  Prove that

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} t \int_0^\infty e^{-tx}f(x) \, dx=1\text{ where }t>0.$$

It seems to me that you want to move the limit inside the integral to get rid of the $e^{-tx}$ and then you can take the integral of $f(x)$.  But I'm not sure.

Comment: If $f$ is defined on $[0,A]$, it doesn't make sense to integrate past $A$ and towards infinity.

Comment: Hint: $t\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}f(x)dx - 1 = t\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}(f(x)-1)dx$.

Answer (score 2):

This is $\int\limits_0^\infty f_t(x)\cdot\mathrm e^{-x}\mathrm dx$ where $f_t:x\mapsto f(x/t)$. By hypothesis $f_t\to1$ pointwise. If, for example, $f$ is bounded, then $f_t$ is uniformly bounded hence by dominated convergence, the integral converges to $\int\limits_0^\infty 1\cdot\mathrm e^{-x}\mathrm dx=1$. (Note that if $f$ is continuous, then $f$ is bounded since $f$ has a limit at infinity.)